# Perlbrew installation through vagrant provision.sh

Tags: vagrant, debian, perlbrew

I want to automate the installation of perlbrew into the vagrant box. I use .sh file to accomplish this.

**provision.sh**

```
apt-get update
sudo -H -u vagrant bash -c " \curl -kL https://install.perlbrew.pl | bash"
sudo -u vagrant bash -c "source ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc"
```

After ssh into the vagrant i expect that

```
$ which perlbrew
```

will return

```
/home/vagrant/perl5/perlbrew/bin/perlbrew
```

but unfortunately it returns nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way the settings applied by your `source ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc` command would be visible in another bash session (and a SSH session executes a new bash process).

You need to add the command `source ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc` to one of the bash "rc" files.

- For a single user with the following command:

  ```
  echo "source ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc" >> ~/.bashrc
  ```
- For all users with the following command:

  ```
  echo "source ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc" >> /etc/bash.bashrc
  ```

This way every time a new bash session is started, it will run `source ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc` and apply the settings.